# Return the max value by group with multiple criteria in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A' )
BRR <- c(62,57,66,53,54,50,55,65,71,53,51,50,58,54,55,57)
val1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
val2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

df <- data.frame(ID, BRR, val1, val2)
```

Output:

```
   ID BRR val1 val2
1   A  62    1    0
2   A  57    1    0
3   A  66    1    0
4   A  53    1    0
5   A  54    1    0
6   A  50    1    0
7   A  55    1    0
8   A  65    2    1
9   A  71    2    1
10  A  53    2    1
11  A  51    3    2
12  A  50    3    2
13  A  58    3    2
14  A  54    3    2
15  A  55    3    2
16  A  57    3    2
```

I would like to get the max value of `BRR` by group (`ID`, `val1`, `val2`). In this case, `ID` has the same value. `Val2` will always be 1 less than `val1` so I am not sure that this column is even required.

So when `val2` is 0, `max_val_KP` will be 0. When `val2` is 1, I would like the max value from `val1` grouping, like so:

```
   ID BRR val1 val2 Max_val_KP
1   A  62    1    0          0
2   A  57    1    0          0
3   A  66    1    0          0
4   A  53    1    0          0
5   A  54    1    0          0
6   A  50    1    0          0
7   A  55    1    0          0
8   A  65    2    1         66
9   A  71    2    1         66
10  A  53    2    1         66
11  A  51    3    2         71
12  A  50    3    2         71
13  A  58    3    2         71
14  A  54    3    2         71
15  A  55    3    2         71
16  A  57    3    2         71
```

I tried:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  filter(va1 == val2) %>%
  group_by(ID, val2) %>%
  mutate(max_val_KP = max(BRR))
```

I also tried:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID, val1 == val2) %>%
  mutate(max_val_KP = max(BRR))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(max_val_KP = replace_na(ave(BRR, val1, FUN = max)[match(val2, val1)], 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 16 × 5
   ID      BRR  val1  val2 max_val_KP
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 A        62     1     0          0
 2 A        57     1     0          0
 3 A        66     1     0          0
 4 A        53     1     0          0
 5 A        54     1     0          0
 6 A        50     1     0          0
 7 A        55     1     0          0
 8 A        65     2     1         66
 9 A        71     2     1         66
10 A        53     2     1         66
11 A        51     3     2         71
12 A        50     3     2         71
13 A        58     3     2         71
14 A        54     3     2         71
15 A        55     3     2         71
16 A        57     3     2         71
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. Accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `val2` is always `val1` + 1, then `val1 == val2` will return nothing because they are never the same. I suggest removing that condition and then also using the `mutate()` function from `dplyr`.

Try this

```r
library(dplyr)
```

```r
df |> group_by(val1, val2) |> 
  mutate(Max_val_KP = max(BRR)) |> ungroup()
```

[image]

Comment: yes that will do it, thank you. However I need to add a new column to my df like the desired output above. Can this be achieved, maybe with `mutate` or similar?

Comment: I modified the answer to better reflect what you are looking for. Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: thank you, that works but when `val2` = 0, I need `Max_val_KP` to be 0, as shown in my desired output above.

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means the most elegant and efficient way to solve the problem, but this occurs to me.

```
ID <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A' )
BRR <- c(62,57,66,53,54,50,55,65,71,53,51,50,58,54,55,57)
val1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
val2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

df <- data.frame(ID, BRR, val1, val2)


Group <- df%>%group_by(val1)%>%summarise(Max_val_KP = max(BRR))
colnames(Group)[1] <- "val2"

Final <- left_join(df, Group)
Final$Max_val_KP[is.na(Final$Max_val_KP)] <- 0
```

As I understood you want the value of Val2 when it is equal to Val1 - 1, that's why I change the name of the column in the Group data frame, so the left join matches Val2 and not Val1.

This give me the same result as you desire output.

Comment: thank you, that will work. Is there any way this can be done without left_join as I have a very large dataset?